# Method for two different types in template class C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I want to do some kind of specialization, something like this:

```
template <typename Type, int Size>
class Example
{
//some values
public:
double length() const;
}

template <typename Type, int Size>
double Example<double, Size>::length() const {...}

template <typename Type, int Size>
double Example<MyType, Size>::length() const {...}
```

Obviously it doesn't work. How should I implement this method? I want Type to be explicitly declared and Size to be variable here.

Comment: Where are those template arguments used? Does `Size` really need to be part of the type?

Comment: You should simply specialize the class:
`template  <int Size>
class Example<double, Size> {
public:
double length() const { /* ... */ }
};`

Comment: I use Size in for loops and it has to be a part of the type, it's defined in header. Type isn't used by any of the definitions.

Comment: Or you could for example use CRTP to only specialize a small part...

Comment: Ok, so, what's your point? It's still part of the type, only `Type` is specialized.

Comment: Take a look at [policy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design). `Length` could be a policy injected by CRTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to specialize the class template for `double` and `MyType`.

```
template <typename Type, int Size>
class Example
{
  public:
    double length() const { /* Use a generic implementation */ }
}

// Specialize for double
template <int Size>
class Example<double, Size>
{
  public:
    double length() const { /* Use a double specific implementation */ }
}

// Specialize for MyType
template <int Size>
class Example<MyType, Size>
{
  public:
    double length() const { /* Use a MyType specific implementation */ }
}
```

The other option is to use another template class/function that can be used by the generic implementation of `Example::length()`.

```
template <typename Type, int Size>
struct Length
{
   // Generic implementation
   static double get() { ... }
}

// Specialize Length for double and MyType

template <int Size>
struct Length<double, Size>
{
   static double get() { ... }
}
template <int Size>
struct Length<MyType, Size>
{
   static double get() { ... }
}

template <typename Type, int Size>
class Example
{
  public:
    double length() const { return Length<Type, Size>::get(); }
}
```

The second approach is better if everything else in `Example` but the `length` member function can be implemented using generic code.

Comment: My class already has many methods but only that one depends on the Type, specializing whole class doesn't seem effective here. Second approach is awesome, thank you!